# I am doing Android Studio. Is there any way that I can go from this canvas back to one my activities?

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, android-activity

I have made a game on canvas.The canvas was created in one of the activities itself.

I want some addition in the `life==0` so that my canvas goes back to an activity
The activity which makes this canvas looks like below.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    back_width=canvas.getWidth();
    back_height=canvas.getHeight();
    if (first==true)
    {
        makeMaze();
    }

    if (time==250)
        ghost_1.setMove(4);
    else if (time==500)
        ghost_2.setMove(3);
    else if (time==750)
        ghost_3.setMove(4);
    else if (time==1000)
        ghost_4.setMove(3);

    drawMaze(canvas);
    movePacman();
    moveGhost();
    ghostWallCollision();
    ghostPacmanCollision(canvas);

    if(life==0) {
        pacman.setCenterX(back_height);
        pacman.setCenterY(back_height);
        pacman.setMove(0);
    }
    invalidate();


}



public class Activity_Game extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_game);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    int oper=intent.getIntExtra("input",1);
    MazeSetup mazeSetup=new MazeSetup(this, oper);
    setContentView(mazeSetup);

    if (mazeSetup.life==0){

        intent=new Intent(Activity_Game.this, Activity_play1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `want some addition in the life==0 so that my canvas goes back to an activity`. To which activity? Was there an activity before? I see that you now start another activity when mazeSetup.life==0.

Comment: yes this canvas is created in an activity, the Activity_Game .